# Do increases (or other changes) to an Echo Knight fighter's movement/speed also apply to the echo?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, movement, fighter, echo-knight

My multiclassed Echo Knight fighter/barbarian has a speed of 50 feet (base 30 ft, barbarian's [Fast Movement](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/barbarian#FastMovement-62) +10 ft, [Mobile](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/mobile) feat +10 feet) – and as a bonus from going into a rage (barbarian's [Instinctive Pounce](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/tcoe/barbarian#InstinctivePounce) +half your speed), I can boost that up to 75 feet total (on one turn).

Assuming I have the echo out, does it still only have 30 feet of movement? Or does it match my speed?

If I am wearing [*Boots of Speed*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/4589-boots-of-speed) (which double my walking speed), does it match? Or does the echo still only have 30 feet of movement?

Comment: I’ve added the [dnd-5e] tag to your question since you mentioned several 5e features.

Answer (score 11):

#### You can move your echo 30 feet, regardless of your speed.

The [Echo Knight](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#EchoKnight)’s [Manifest Echo](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#ManifestEcho-1810360) feature states (EGtW, p. 183):

> On your turn, you can mentally command the echo to move up to 30 feet in any direction

There is nothing here about this value increasing when your speed increases, so it doesn’t.

Comment: This is a boon for an EK with Speed 25 - the Echo always moves 30 feet.